# How to setup llvm in kdevelop?

Tags: c++, debugging, llvm, lldb, kdevelop

Is there any way to set up kdevelop to debug with the lldb?

Can I set up in such a way, that I  have all the nice features like auto-completion and debugging with breakpoints and step by step Debugging?

Answer (score 0):

This would likely require some work by the kdevelop maintainers to support.  lldb is structured as a library (`LLDB.framework`) which client programs (currently on Mac OS X, command-line `lldb` and `Xcode` are two clients) use to provide debugging capabilities.

Adding lldb support in another IDE like kdevelop means that the kdevelop developers would need to add support for the lldb library APIs.  It's (IMO) a clean API but it is a lot of work to add an entirely new debugger to an IDE.  And given that kdevelop looks like it is multi-platform and lldb is still primarily a Mac OS X debugger (although the FreeBSD and Linux ports are making great progress thanks to a number of contributors working on those platforms!), I don't know if they will be eager to add support for it until it is a strong debugger on all their supported platforms.